# error:conflicting types for int32_t

Tags: c, gcc, bison, flex-lexer, lpc

I am working on `lpcxpresso (lpc1768)`. I have included a `.h` file and two `.c` files in my already written code (these files have been created using `flex` and `bison`). I want to use the option "Newlib(semihost)" under "quick settings". When i build my code it shows some errors:

> "c:\nxp\lpcxpresso_6.1.2_177\lpcxpresso\tools\bin../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.6.2/../../../../arm-none-eabi/include/newlib_inc/stdint.h:79:21:
>   error: conflicting types for 'int32_t'"
>
> "c:\nxp\lpcxpresso_6.1.2_177\lpcxpresso\tools\bin../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.6.2/../../../../arm-none-eabi/include/newlib_inc/stdint.h:80:23:
>   error: conflicting types for 'uint32_t'"

When I switch to library Redlib then these errors do not occur but some other problems arise. I want to use Newlib.

Why these errors are occurring ? What do I need to do?

Comment: grep for `typedef * int32_t` into your files and headers

Comment: Do I need to define type in the files which I give as input to flex and bison after which .c and .h files are generated?

Comment: If grep is not at hand you can read the output of the preprocessor to see (a) how the `int32_t` typedefs look like (b) where the typedefs are located. After that you have to rule out what shall be dropped.

Comment: I have not defined these things by my own. While I switch the library this problem doesn't occur. This issue is related to library. There is no error in the code which I have created as I have made it to run independently where it runs properly.

Answer (score 0):

This error arises due to multiple deffinitions of int32_t and uint32_t in different header files. Check the build log to find any information related to where this multiple definition/declaration happened. See if you can use the system header file for these type definitions, and in case there is additional code in your header, use conditional macros to disable typedef part. Hope this helps.